# Making a function wait for done

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have a function like this:

```
a: function (val) {
    ajaxcall.done(function() {
        console.log("Done");
    }
}
```

I want to write another function which calls `a`, then wait until `a` is done (so the stuff inside the `.done()` executes, then it'll continue with the rest. Something like this:

```
console.log("beginning");
a("test");
console.log("End");
```

Would that print out

```
beginning
done
end
```

or would it sometimes be

```
beginning
end
done
```

depending on if the ajax calls take a long time?

Comment: just use ajax synchronous call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

Comment: Try not using sync ajax... You could block the thread unnecessarily. Google Dev Tools actually issue warnings on the console when you start using sync XHR.

Comment: @roman really really bad idea, not just for the reasons mentioned by noderman, but it's also deprecated because of how bad it is for the experience

Comment: @JuanMendes, ok, I think that I would agree with that

Comment: @vove wrong question, that's talking about the async attribute of the script tag

Comment: @JuanMendes, I have not been using JQuery for a long time(prefer native js) and I forgot about such stuff as `$.Deferred`.

Answer (score 1):

That will always print:

```
beginning
End
Done
```

Even if the ajax call is instant, because JavaScript always completes the current execution thread before starting another one.

Answer (score 1):

For the example you provided, it should print the done after the end

To wait for your function to end you can write something like that

```
a: function(val, done) {
  ajaxcall.done(done)
}

//or if you want to do something before declaring it's done

a: function(val, done) {
  ajaxcall.done(function() {
    console.log('done');
    done();
  })
}
```

And afterwards use it like that

```
console.log("beginning");
a("test", function() {
  console.log("End");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.done()` can accept an array of functions to call

```js
function ajaxcall() {
  return new $.Deferred(function(d) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      d.resolve()
    }, Math.random() * 3000)
  }).promise()
}

function complete() {
  console.log("End")
}

function a(val) {
  ajaxcall().done([
    function() {
      console.log("Done");
    },
    complete
  ])
}

a()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: See [`deferred.done( doneCallbacks [, doneCallbacks ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/#deferred-done-doneCallbacks-doneCallbacks) **doneCallbacks** Type: `Function()` _"A function, or array of functions, that are called when the Deferred is resolved."_

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in AJAX callback to call your function on complete.

```
function loadME() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
//if the data is downloaded and you receive no server errors, 
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     yourcallback();
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "url for your query goes here", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your api url here",
}).done(function() {
  yourcallback();
});
```